# Angular SPA adal login calls Azure AD and reply URL, but doesn't return userInfo or isAuthenticated

Tags: angularjs, azure-active-directory, adal

I'm hoping to use Azure's Active Directory Service for authentication as part of an Angular SPA. To that end, I am trying to use [Active Directory Authentication Library (ADAL) for JavaScript](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js). But while it seems to correctly redirect to login services and, after credential entry, returns to the Reply URL, I am not able to get userInfo.isAuthenticated (userInfo is empty) within my controller.

How would I go about debugging why authentication doesn't appear to be finishing?

The following is my app code:

```
'use strict';

var myClientApplication = angular.module('myApplication', [
    'ngRoute', 'myControllerModule', 'AdalAngular'
]);

Logging = {
    level: 3,
    log: function (message) {
        console.log(message);
    }
};

var appStart = function($routeProvider, $httpProvider, adalProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/xxx', {
        templateUrl: '/app/views/xxx.html',
        controller: 'xxxController',
        requireADLogin: true
    }).when('/home', {
        templateUrl: '/app/views/home.html',
        controller: 'homeController',
        requireADLogin: false
    }).otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/home'
    });

    adalProvider.init({
        instance: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/',
        tenant: 'mydefaultdomain.onmicrosoft.com',
        clientId: '91dc4efa-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-c579f5f07ceb',
        endPoints: {},
        //anonymousEndpoints: {},
        extraQueryParameter: 'nux=1',
        cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
    }, $httpProvider);
};

myClientApplication.config(['$routeProvider', '$httpProvider',  'adalAuthenticationServiceProvider', appStart]);
```

My controller code:

```
'use strict'

var myControllerModule = angular.module('myControllerModule', []);

myControllerModule.controller('homeController', ['$scope',   'adalAuthenticationService', function ($scope, adalService) {
    $scope.userInfo = adalService.userInfo;
    $scope.login = function() {
        adalService.login()
    }
    $scope.logout = function() {
        adalService.logOut()
    }
}]);

myControllerModule.controller('xxxController', ['$scope', function($scope){}]);
```

The view for the home controller is:

```
<div class="container">
<button class="btn btn-primary" title="Login" ng-click="login()">Login</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary" title="Logout" ng-click="logout()">Logout</button>

<p>status:{{userInfo.isAuthenticated}}</p>
<p>user:{{userInfo.userName}}</p>
<p>aud:{{userInfo.profile.aud}}</p>
<p>iss:{{userInfo.profile.iss}}</p>
```

Which results in:

```
status:false
user:
aud:
iss:
```

Within Azure management, I have an Active Directory (Status=Active), with a defined Application with the following configuration:

- sign-on URL: http://127.0.0.1:8080/app/index.html
- client id: 91dc4efa-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-c579f5f07ceb
- reply id: http://127.0.0.1:8080/app/index.html

The following appears in the log messaging after login button press:

```
// I think this is coming to index
app.js:10 Wed, 15 Feb 2017 22:45:09 GMT:1.0.13-VERBOSE: Location change event from http://127.0.0.1:8080/app/index.html#!#id_token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJ…-4325-bcff-5bb5e5a552b9&session_state=709884dd-ad85-4b58-b403-d3155ab441cc to http://127.0.0.1:8080/app/index.html#!#id_token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJ…-4325-bcff-5bb5e5a552b9&session_state=709884dd-ad85-4b58-b403-d3155ab441cc
// I think this is the redirect for the home controller
app.js:10 Wed, 15 Feb 2017 22:45:10 GMT:1.0.13-VERBOSE: Location change event from http://127.0.0.1:8080/app/index.html#!#id_token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJ…-4325-bcff-5bb5e5a552b9&session_state=709884dd-ad85-4b58-b403-d3155ab441cc to http://127.0.0.1:8080/app/index.html#!/home#id_token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbG…-4325-bcff-5bb5e5a552b9&session_state=709884dd-ad85-4b58-b403-d3155ab441cc
// Don't know what this means?
app.js:10 Wed, 15 Feb 2017 22:45:10 GMT:1.0.13-VERBOSE: Url: /app/views/home.html maps to resource: null
```

Versions:

- adal-angular: 1.0.13
- angular: 1.6.2
- node: 6.9.5
- npm: 4.1.2 OS:
- Windows 10

Running using 'npm start' where start=http://127.0.0.1:8080/../app.js

Comment: Have you tried binding to `userInfo` without setting it in your controller? It is an object exposed from the root scope so you shouldn't need to do this: `$scope.userInfo = adalService.userInfo;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was caused by the malformed redirect URL which contains the character '**!**'.

After I modify the code below, I can get the authentication information well:

```
var appStart = function ($routeProvider, $httpProvider, adalProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');//add this line to fix the URL
    $routeProvider.when('/xxx', {
        templateUrl: 'spa/app/views/xxx.html',
        controller: 'xxxController',
        requireADLogin: true
    }).when('/home', {
        templateUrl: '/app/views/home.html',
        controller: 'homeController',
        requireADLogin: false
    }).otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/home'
    });

    adalProvider.init({
        instance: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/',
        tenant: 'xxx.onmicrosoft.com',
        clientId: 'xxxx-5d42-4e62-858e-9d5864b71f7a',
        endPoints: {},
        popUp:true,
        //anonymousEndpoints: {},
        extraQueryParameter: 'nux=1',
        cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
    }, $httpProvider);
};

//add $locationProvider
myClientApplication.config(['$routeProvider', '$httpProvider', 'adalAuthenticationServiceProvider', '$locationProvider', appStart]
```

Please let me know it it helps.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Just for trouble-shooting purposes, how did you figure that out? BTW, I was using the following example, which makes no mention of the above-mentioned fix: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-devquickstarts-angular

Comment: Also I think you meant 'malformed' not 'mailform', right?

Comment: Yes, you were correct. This was a typo and I have changed the post. And I figure that out by comparing the code with a sample which worked for me before:)

Comment: Thanks a bunch, saved me many head bangs on the table. This fixed a different problem for me. After ADAL authentication, ADAL would constantly reload the authenticated view, on and on and on. Something we noticed is that it was adding /#!/ like localhost:1000/#!/#view.html. That guided me to your post and it fixed it for us.