# adalAuthenticationService.getUser() does't work in adal-angular wrapper

Tags: adal, adal.js

I have provider configuration like below in my app config file:

```
adalProvider.init(
                {
                    tenant: 'f1fe7433-5ecf-46a6-995c-98cc6514b738',
                    clientId: 'e420016e-13d9-4035-b25e-75a4dbaa37d4'
                },
                //$httpProvider   // pass http provider to inject request interceptor to attach tokens
                );
```

I have called **adalAuthenticationService.login()** from my controller file, it is redirecting with token id as query string that means login is done successfully.  After redirecting the page  calling userInfo property but I am getting isAuthenticated is coming false. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It may be the issue causing by $locationProvider.hashPrefix. See [Angular SPA adal login calls Azure AD and reply URL, but doesn't return userInfo or isAuthenticated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42261710/angular-spa-adal-login-calls-azure-ad-and-reply-url-but-doesnt-return-userinfo). May be it helpful for you.

Comment: I have disabled //$httpProvider in my setting because it is adding token id in all of my navigation which is annoying. It could be reason of happening not getting user info?

Comment: As the  http provider injects request interceptor to attach tokens, so if you disable it the token will not be attached. Enable it and try again.

Comment: I am getting such error: Error: [$compile:tpload] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.4/$compile/tpload?p0=.%2FMyTemplete.html&p1=undefined&p2=undefined and headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"},"data":"User login is required|login required"}

Comment: It is happening because I didn't add stateProvider. Does it required state provider? I didn't add it because I don't have any routing in my angularjs project.

Comment: enabling $httpProvider is getting those errors, it is trying to add authentication in all of my api request and asking for user login.